# Theme not picked up by all Activity views

Tags: android, view, themes

I have this custom style:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppText">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/book_family</item>
    </style>
</resource>
```

I applied this new style as a theme to one of my activities by adding the following in my manifest:

```
...
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppText"/>
...
```

The result is not what I expected. Only a few views picked up the custom style. The following image shows two views. The first FIELD ONE is okay. The FIELD TWO field won't pick up the style.

[image]

Here is the definition of those two fields:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:imeActionId="6"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Please, any idea?

Comment: If you remove the input type from the edittext, is it ok? it might be the password...

Comment: I cannot remove the inputtype as this is a password field.

Comment: I just want to understand if this is due to the password

Comment: Yes, due to the password field. Any idea?

Comment: I have also checked other solutions here in SO, the common solution is to remove the InputType. In my case, I cannot remove this as this is a password field.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I spent a few ours on it and I'm posting my answer now.

Comment: did you try to use `parent="@android:style/TextAppearance"` in your theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only one view was affected, I did not mind solving it in Java with the following:

```
TextInputLayout til_passw = findViewById(R.id.til_password);
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.book_family);
til_passw.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like themes don't apply to password fields, probably for security reasons. But I have found a work around to style the password field. You only need to add 2 more attributes to your custom style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppText">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/book_family</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

And then use [`app:hintTextAppearance`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHintTextAppearance(int)) on your `TextInputLayout`. Your password field  would look like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.AppText">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:imeActionId="6"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Explanation: As mentioned on the documentation, hintTextAppearance:

> Sets the hint text color, size, style from the specified
>   TextAppearance resource.

Now when you use your style as it is, it will only change the font-family, but keeping the `textSize` at 8sp and the `textColor` black. That's why I added these 2 attributes to your custom style.

Comment: Hmm.. This is really weird. This solution doesn't work on my project.

Comment: What's your compileSdkVersion and what's your device's Android version?

Comment: compiledSdkVersion is 26; minSdkVersion is 19; my device is Android 7.1.1 (Nougat)

Comment: I tested under the same conditions. Is your support library up to date?

Comment: yes it is updated. i am using 26.1 for support library.

Comment: may I ask how did you define your AppTheme style?

Comment: Same as you did on your question.